# C++ parameter match/deducing

Tags: android, c++

I read some code that I quite don't understand in Android Oreo sourcecode.

First, class **IOMXNode** has a function:

```
class IOMXNode : public IInterface {
public:
+-- 46 lines: DECLARE_HYBRID_META_INTERFACE(OMXNode, IOmxNode);-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    // Instructs the component to use the buffer passed in via |omxBuf| on the
    // specified port. Returns in |*buffer| the buffer id that the component
    // assigns to this buffer. |omxBuf| must be one of:
    // 1) OMXBuffer::sPreset for meta-mode,
    // 2) type kBufferTypeANWBuffer for non-meta-graphic buffer mode,
    // 3) type kBufferTypeSharedMem for bytebuffer mode.
    virtual status_t useBuffer(
            OMX_U32 port_index, const OMXBuffer &omxBuf, buffer_id *buffer) = 0;
```

the **useBuffer()** has three parameter, one of it is **const OMXBuffer&**, it defines like:

```
class OMXBuffer {
public:
    // sPreset is used in places where we are referring to a pre-registered
    // buffer on a port. It has type kBufferTypePreset and mRangeLength of 0.
    static OMXBuffer sPreset;

    // Default constructor, constructs a buffer of type kBufferTypeInvalid.
    OMXBuffer();

    // Constructs a buffer of type kBufferTypePreset with mRangeOffset set to
    // |codecBuffer|'s offset and mRangeLength set to |codecBuffer|'s size (or 0
    // if |codecBuffer| is NULL).
    OMXBuffer(const sp<MediaCodecBuffer> &codecBuffer);

    // Constructs a buffer of type kBufferTypePreset with specified mRangeOffset
    // and mRangeLength.
    OMXBuffer(OMX_U32 rangeOffset, OMX_U32 rangeLength);

    // Constructs a buffer of type kBufferTypeSharedMem.
    OMXBuffer(const sp<IMemory> &mem);
```

then there is somewhere call this function like:

```
sp<IOMXNode> mOMXNode;
...
sp<IMemory> mem;
...
err = mOMXNode->useBuffer(portIndex, mem, &info.mBufferID);
```

So, why `sp<IMemory>` can match the function **useBuffer()**'s second parameter type **const OMXBuffer&** directly?

all I can put this together is somehow, compiler use `sp<IMemory>` and construct a **OMXBuffer**, then match the **useBuffer()** second parameter.

is this belong type deducing or something else that i don't know?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The important lines are these (from the `OMXBuffer` class):

```
// Constructs a buffer of type kBufferTypeSharedMem.
OMXBuffer(const sp<IMemory> &mem);
```

That [*converting constructor*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/converting_constructor) makes it possible to create an `OMXBuffer` object from a `sp<IMemory>` object.

That means what's really happening is

```
err = mOMXNode->useBuffer(portIndex, OMXBuffer(mem), &info.mBufferID);
```

That is, a temporary `OMXBuffer` object is created from the `mem` object. Then a reference to that temporary `OMXBuffer` object is passed to the `useBuffer` function. And once the `useBuffer` function returns the temporary `OMXBuffer` object is destructed.

Comment: Thanks a lot,  I get it after read  some explanations about  *converting constructor*.

Answer (score 0):

When a copy constructor is defined with just one argument, it is a converting constructor.

From [cpp reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/converting_constructor)

> It is said that a converting constructor specifies an implicit conversion from the types of its arguments (if any) to the type of its class

So when you pass `mem` to useBuffer as second parameter, it is being converted to `OMXBuffer&` by using the converting constructor.

Comment: It's not really a *copy* constructor though, but a [*converting* constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/converting_constructor). And since the `useBuffer` function takes its argument by reference, no copy-constructor will be called.